# How can I compress resources into a single file in Java?

Tags: java, assets, compression

Today I've finished my game, but there's a problem. There're more than 500+ images in my resources folder and I want to compress them into a single file, like other games do (for example put everything in a .pak file). I've searched on the internet, but I can't find something that tells about how to do it with Java.

There's maybe a library that I can use to avoid that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this for deployment purposes? Will the files be uncompressed when the game is installed, or will the game load the files directly from the compressed package?

Comment: Yes, it is. I don't want others to modify easily the resources. @KaareZ

Comment: Then I don't know much about it. You could also try to put your resources inside the jar?

Comment: I've tried it, but you can decompile it and get all the files.

Comment: @KaareZ What would stop you from opening the .jar with win rar and viewing the images then ?

Comment: +@Shiro I didn't thought about it.

Comment: Try having a look at JarProtector (http://www.bfa-it.com/?lang=en&id=products/jarprotector)

Comment: see also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/37648/how-can-you-put-all-images-from-a-game-to-1-file for some ideas

Comment: To stop others from modifying the contents of files that you load, you calculate use MD5 or SHA-256 checksums of these files and check that they match values that you have hard coded in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all of the resources in a ZIP archive.

Rename the file from `example.zip` to `example.pak` (or whatever else you want).

Lastly, uncompress the archive and load all of your resources.

```
ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("/external/path/to/test.zip");

Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();

while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
    ZipEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
    InputStream stream = zipFile.getInputStream(entry);
}
```

You can also read an archive from inside of your JAR file.

```
URL url = new URL("jar:file:/path/of/file.jar!/resources.pak");
```

The location of the running JAR can be easily retrieved (as long as the class that this is called from has been loaded from that JAR).

```
new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

Comment: Perfect solution to my problem. I raccomand it!